# Error installing slpd

Tags: apt, cups-lpd, crouton

I installed crouton with XFCE and trusty less than half an hour ago. I then transferred some files from a USB stick onto my desktop, used the built in browser briefly, and used apt-get to install a large number of packages. I encountered an error with `slpd`, and thought that I might try to install it again, to see what the problem is.

```
sudo apt-get install slpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
slpd is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up slpd (1.2.1-9) ...
+ [ configure = configure ]
+ dpkg --compare-versions  le 1.2.1-7.6
+ echo Reinstalling init script for new priorities ...
Reinstalling init script for new priorities ...
+ update-rc.d slpd remove
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/slpd exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)
dpkg: error processing package slpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 slpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `sudo apt-get clean` did not fix my problem. This is an almost completely fresh installation. I am removing the program slpd needed, but every time I try to use `apt-get install`, I get this dpkg error. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are affected by the bug reported in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openslp-dfsg/+bug/1047561). A suggested fix is to open `/var/lib/dpkg/info/slpd.postinst` and edit it. So, open your terminal and type:

> `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/slpd.postinst`

and add `-f` to the line no:9 so that it becomes:

> `update-rc.d -f slpd remove`

Save and then try installing again.